# Rails ActiveRecord Query Date Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use the following line in my controller to capture all tasks due less than a week from the current date:

```
@due_this_week = current_user.tasks.where(due_date: Date.today..1.week.from_now)
```

For some reason it's not finding any results even I know I have tasks due within four and six days.  This is the only instance variable using a range query.  I have another one that works fine to find overdue tasks:

```
@overdue = current_user.tasks.where("due_date <= ?", Date.today)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my controller somehow wasn't set up correctly and was no longer saving the `current_user`'s ID when creating new assignments, which is why they weren't being found.  I figured this out using the rails console and running a find on the last few assignments submitted.  The `user_id` was set to `nil`.  Thanks for the assist @mu is too short.

Answer (score 97):

Should be:

```
@due_this_week = current_user.tasks.where(due_date: 1.week.ago..Date.today)
```

Comment: How does that match "all tasks due less than a week from the current date"?

Comment: OP made a mistake, sorry.

Comment: Sweet. That's all.

Comment: It's been a while since I up voted this bad boy, and it came in handy again today!

Answer (score 5):

FYI you can also use one sided ranges.

For all calls with due date from 1 week ago

```
@due_this_week = current_user.tasks.where(due_date: 1.week.ago..)
```

or for all calls with due date up to today

```
@due_this_week = current_user.tasks.where(due_date: ..Date.today)
```