# How to parameterize a date range in a rails (postgres) query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Just like the title asks, how do I include a date range in a query?

For example, let's say I have a model called `VisitToGrandma` and it has a field called `visit_date`. Now, I want to find all visits to grandmothers that happened in the last month.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
VisitToGrandma.where("? @> visit_date", (1.month.ago..Time.now))
```

However, this produces the query:

> SELECT "visits_to_grandmas".* FROM "visits_to_grandmas" WHERE ('2018-07-01','2018-07-02','2018-07-03','2018-07-04','2018-07-05','2018-07-06','2018-07-07','2018-07-08','2018-07-09','2018-07-10','2018-07-11','2018-07-12','2018-07-13','2018-07-14','2018-07-15','2018-07-16','2018-07-17','2018-07-18','2018-07-19','2018-07-20','2018-07-21','2018-07-22','2018-07-23','2018-07-24','2018-07-25','2018-07-26','2018-07-27','2018-07-28','2018-07-29','2018-07-30','2018-07-31','2018-08-01' @> visit_date)

What's the correct way to parameterize this?

*Yes, I know for this fictional example, I can just use the start and end date and use `BETWEEN` or some other operators to do this without using an actual date range, but that's not what I'm asking about.*

Edit to point out how this question is different from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413456/rails-activerecord-query-date-range):

That question is just about finding a date in a range, my question is asking how to actually parameterize a range object so that all of postgresql's daterange operators can be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord Query Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413456/rails-activerecord-query-date-range)

Comment: @jvillian, yeah, they are very similar questions, but the context of that one is "no results appear", while the context of mine is "it is producing an incorrect query". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Recognizing the difference in contexts, is the approach applicable? `VisitToGrandma.where(visit_date: 1.month.ago..Time.now)`?

Comment: @jvillian, for this fictional example, yes, but I need to know how to include date ranges in order to use all of postgresql's daterange operators, not just find if a date is in this range

Comment: Apologies for my confusion, but do you mean when the field type is a postgres `daterange`?

Comment: @jvillian, yeah, possibly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I recently mentioned in another [PostgreSQL/range/ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574272/479863) answer, AR's integration with PostgreSQL's range types is limited.

You can get around that by semi-manually producing the string representation of the range you want:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(1.month.ago.to_date .. Time.now.to_date)
```

Not the `#to_date` calls to get dates rather than timestamps. You could also say:

```
today = Date.today
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(today.months_ago(1) .. today)
```

Mixing that in with your query:

```
today = Date.today
VisitToGrandma.where(
  '? @> visit_date',
  VisitToGrandma.connection.type_cast(today.months_ago(1) .. today)
)
```

Depending on context, you might have easier/cleaner access to `connection`. You might want to include a typecast just to be sure nothing is misinterpreted:

```
today = Date.today
VisitToGrandma.where(
  '?::daterange @> visit_date',
  VisitToGrandma.connection.type_cast(today.months_ago(1) .. today)
)
```

Comment: Using the `connection.type_cast` made it happy. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you'll need to abuse a bit of `where` placeholders to accomplish this with ActiveRecord

```
VisitToGrandma.where(
  ":range::daterange @> date",
  range: '[2011-01-01,2011-03-01)'
)
```

Note the symbols `[` and `)` in the range, more information on the Postgres doc
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-IO

Comment: Why use `tsrange` when `daterange` is available and we're dealing with dates? You can use `connection.type_cast` to produce a string in the appropriate format, `#type_cast` also properly differentiates between `..` and `...` ranges.

Comment: You're right @muistooshort, `daterange` is the correct operator here to compare dates, not timestamps. I'll update my answer thanks. Woudl you mind posting another answer with your suggestions?

Comment: I think my existing answer covers it well enough but feel free to update yours.